# How to call multiple Uni concurrently

Tags: java, concurrency, quarkus, mutiny

Recently, I'm working on a project where I have 2 make 2 asynchronous calls at the same time. Since I'm working with Quarkus, I ended up trying to make use of Mutiny and the vert.x library. However, I can not get my code working with Unis. In the below code, I would imagine that both Unis would be called and the Uni that returns fastest would be returned. However, it seems that when combining Unis it simply returns the first one in the list, even though the first uni should take a longer time.

The below code prints out `one one` when it should print out `two two` since the uniFast should finish first. How do I combine Unis and have the faster one return first?

```
@Test
    public void testUniJion(){
        var uniSLow = Uni.createFrom().item(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "one";
        });

        var uniFast = Uni.createFrom().item(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "two";
        });

        var resp = Uni.join().first(uniSLow,uniFast).withItem().await().indefinitely();
        System.out.println(resp);

        var resp2 = Uni.combine().any().of(uniSLow,uniFast).await().indefinitely();
        System.out.println(resp2);
    }
```

Note: This is not the actual code I am trying to implement. In my code, I am trying to fetch from 2 different databases. However, one database often has a lot more latency than the other. However, Uni seems to always wait for the slower database. I'm simply trying to understand Mutiny and Uni's better so I made this code example.

Comment: Mutiny is a so-called "reactive programming" library. You don't specify that your `Uni`s should be "executed" on an extra thread ("executed" in quotes, because there's a difference between subscription and emission and you can configure threads for those separately), so the assumption is that they are non-blocking and they are all executed on the same thread. Therefore, since you ask for the slow `Uni` to be executed first (and the fast one second), you'll always end up with the slow one "winning". See e.g. https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/guides/emit-subscription for more info.

Comment: @Ladicek How do I specify that Uni's should be executed on a different thread. By using the emitOn and subscribe on that you linked too? Honestly, I feel like that goes against my understanding of what Unis are.  In the documentation it says
"Typically, Uni<T> are great to represent asynchronous actions such as a remote procedure call, an HTTP request, or an operation producing a single result."  
source: https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/getting-started/creating-unis

Comment: Also, 
"It is common to trigger several concurrent operations, then join on the results. For instance you can make HTTP requests to 3 different HTTP APIs, then collect all HTTP responses. Or you can just take the response from the one who was the fastest.

Uni offers the join group to assemble all results from a list of Uni, pick the first one that terminates, or pick the first one that terminates with a value."
source: https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/guides/joining-unis

Comment: If unis are supposed to be asynchronous, why wouldn't they be run on different threads if joining them?

Comment: Asynchronous is an overloaded word and means different things to different people. For some, it means "run on a different thread", while for others, it means "run on an event loop, because it's non-blocking". As I said, Mutiny is a so-called "reactive programming" library, so it is most often used to orchestrate non-blocking operations (such as the HTTP client example you mention). There's a lot of materials on the web around what non-blocking IO is, I suggest you read up on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not telling `Mutiny` on which thread should run each uni. If I add a `System.out` to your example:

```
// Slow and Fast for the different Uni
System.out.println( "Slow - " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + ":" + Thread.currentThread().getName() );
```

I get the following output:

```
Slow - 1:Test worker
one
Slow - 1:Test worker
Fast - 1:Test worker
one
```

The output shows that everything runs on the same thread and therefore when we block the first one, the second one is blocked too.
That's why the output is `one one`.

One way to run the uni in parallel is to use a different executor at subscription:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 5 );
uniSlow = uniSlow.runSubscriptionOn( executorService );
uniFast = uniFast.runSubscriptionOn( executorService );
```

Now, when I run the test, I have the expected output:

```
Slow - 16:pool-3-thread-1
Fast - 17:pool-3-thread-2
two
Slow - 18:pool-3-thread-3
Fast - 19:pool-3-thread-4
two
```

Note that this time Slow and Fast are running on different threads.

The Mutiny guide has a section about the difference between [emitOn vs. runSubscriptionOn](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/2.1.0/guides/emit-on-vs-run-subscription-on/) and [some examples on how to change the emission thread](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/2.1.0/guides/emission-threads/).